# Creating enclosed polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a pole data connected to houses. I wanted to create an enclosed polygon with the pole and all its corresponding demand points.

How can I do this?

Input

[image]

Output
[image]

I am using QGIS.

Comment: i think what you are looking at is https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389981/creating-individual-polygons-based-on-sequentially-numbered-points-in-qgis

Answer (score 2):

*This result assumes that* :

- there are 3 layers : `poles` (point), `homes` (point) and `connections` (linestring)

**Process** :

1. Open Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Open the [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) algorithm
3. Configure it as follow :

   - `Input layer` : `poles`
   - `Output geometry type` : `Polygon`
   - `Geometry expression` : the expression below, explaned with comments in the code (read by order)
   - Click on the <kbd>Run</kbd> button

```sql
-- 1: as a variable named @pole_connections : multilinestring geometry of all the connections lines that intersects the pole geometry
with_variable(
    'pole_connections',
    collect_geometries(
        overlay_intersects(
            layer:='connections',
            expression:=$geometry
        )
    ),
    -- 5: create a convex hull polygon from the multipoint geometry
    convex_hull(
        -- 4: make a multipoint geometry of pole + homes points
        collect_geometries(
            -- 3: append to this array the pole geometry
            array_append(
                -- 2: make an array with all the homes point geometries
                -- that intersects @pole_connections
                aggregate(
                    layer:='homes',
                    aggregate:='array_agg',
                    expression:=$geometry,
                    filter:=intersects($geometry, @pole_connections)
                ),
                $geometry  -- geometry of the pole
            )
        )
    )
)
```